# How to read which pipelines a user is allowed to run as downstream jobs in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I want to add a feature in my groovy script to allow users run other jobs sequencially once the job they have selected has finished if they input the name of the job in a text field created for such purpose in the configuration

As far as I know the pipelines are run as default as the SYSTEM user and therefore there are no restrictions on what pipelines can be run. In my case a user can only access its predeterminated folder to run his jobs, but it would be possible to add manually in the config a job from another folder to be run sequentially even if he has no rights to access such folder. This is what I want to avoid

I'm aware of the RBAC plugin but I think it wont suffice as it is useful only to restrict access to folders. Correct me if Im wrong

https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/cloud-secure-guide/rbac

I would like to know if there is a way to display in the configuration a drop down menu not with static content, but with the pipelines a user is allowed to run based on its folder access rights. If not, I would like to at least gather the number of jobs a user is authorized to run in order to block them in the groovy script if a user has entered in the text field a pipeline on which he has no access rights.

Answer (score 0):

The Role-based Authorization Strategy plugin can do that: https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy/

You just have to pick the "Role Based Strategy" in your Manage Jenkins -> Security -> Authentication -> Authorization configuration part.

Then define the Item roles in Manage Jenkins -> Manage and Assign Roles -> Manage Roles
The created Item role requires a pattern, after creation it would show matching jobs.
The permission are such you can even hide the jobs from some users.

Don't forget to assign the role to your users.